# How far does the new metaspace go and when will it stop

Tags: java, java-8

With Java 8 removing PermGen, we can no longer use the JVM arguments to change it or limit it.

But if I have a memory leak in my app, I want to know about it. I do not want the JVM to allocate gigabytes of memory.

So my question is: how far will it go, when will it stop, and can I limit it from the OS (using `ulimit`)?

Comment: http://javaeesupportpatterns.blogspot.com/2013/02/java-8-from-permgen-to-metaspace.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, by default metaspace is unlimited. Not to worry: you can still set an upper limit on the amount of metaspace available to the JVM. [`-XX:MaxMetaSpaceSize`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/java.html#BABFAFAE) to the rescue.

http://java.dzone.com/articles/java-8-permgen-metaspace